# Wind Speed / Dir and Gust Speed US Pacific Southwest

Tags: data-request, meteorology

I am looking for wind speed, wind direction, and gust speed (optional) data for the Pacific Southwest region of the US - more specifically for the Northern California region including Napa, Lake and Sonoma counties. The time range would be for the 2017 year, with a temporal resolution of 3 hours, and a spatial resolution of at least 5km.

I understand this type of data can be modeled from observed readings at weather stations across the US, and it is fine if the data is derived model data. I have looked into some data and I came up with the following list (sourced from NOAA):

1. https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/model-data/model-datasets/service-records-retention-system-srrs
2. https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/model-data/model-datasets/north-american-regional-reanalysis-narr
3. https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/model-data/model-datasets/national-digital-forecast-database-ndfd & companion dataset https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/model-data/model-datasets/national-digital-guidance-database-ndgd
4. https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/model-data/model-datasets/climate-forecast-system-version2-cfsv2

I hope to get my hands on more regionally focused data - specifically for the region I am looking into.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're saying you've found point data (from hourly observations) but are looking for area-based data (ie, something above and beyond simple interpolation)?